# My VF page is loading both Mobile & Desktop view

Tags: json, javascript-remoting, style

I am using JSON to populate data tables in my page. very Strangly, it's loading the data in both Mobile & Desktop view.

Can anyone help me with this?

Attaching the screen shot. [image: Both view Loading on pageload.]

PFB the code for the VF page.

{!$Label.PP_PartnerPortal} | Lead

```
<script>
    function acceptLeadJS(val){
        acceptLeadActionFn(val); 
         window.location.assign('{!SITE_PREFIX}/PPLeadHome');
    }       
    function leadInboxDetailJS(val1, val2){
        if(val2 == null || val2 == ''){
            window.location.assign('{!SITE_PREFIX}/PPLeadHome?type=Inbox&id='+val1);
        }else{
            window.location.assign('{!SITE_PREFIX}/PPLeadHome?type=Allinbox&id='+val1);
        }
    }
    function leadReferralDetailJS(val1, val2){
        if(val2 == null || val2 == ''){
            window.location.assign('{!SITE_PREFIX}/PPLeadHome?type=Referral&id='+val1);
        }else{
            window.location.assign('{!SITE_PREFIX}/PPLeadHome?type=Allreferral&id='+val1);
        }

    }
    function leadActiveDetailJS(val1, val2){
    if(val2 == null || val2 == ''){
            window.location.assign('{!SITE_PREFIX}/PPLeadHome?type=Active&id='+val1);
        }else{
            window.location.assign('{!SITE_PREFIX}/PPLeadHome?type=Allactive&id='+val1);
        }

    }
    function leadDeclineDetailJS(val){

        window.location.assign('{!SITE_PREFIX}/PPLeadHome?type=AllDeclined&id='+val);          

    }
    function leadAllDetailJS(val){
     window.location.assign('{!SITE_PREFIX}/PPLeadHome?type=All&id='+val);

    }
    function checkStatusJS(val){
        checkStatusActionFn(val);    
        window.location.assign('{!SITE_PREFIX}/PPLeadHome');
    } 
    function viewDealJS(val){
        viewDealActionFn(val);
    }

psJQ(function ($) {
      'use strict';

      //-leads inbox table
      $('.leads-inbox-table').DataTable({
          "ajax": "{!SITE_PREFIX}/PPDTJSONGENERATOR?Type=LeadInbox&input1={!SITE_Account.Id}",
          "columns": [
          {
              "mData": "Company",
              "mRender": function(data, type, full){
                return '<a  href = "#" onclick="leadInboxDetailJS(\'' + full.Id + '\', \'\');">' +data+ '</a>';
               }
          },{
              "mData": "Contact"
          },{
              "mData": "Title"
          },{
              "mData": "Location"
          },{
              "mData": "dateAssigned"
          },{
              "width": "10%",
              "mData": "daysRemaining"
          },{
              "mData": "action",
              "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                 return '<button type = "Button" class="btn primary" onclick="acceptLeadJS(\'' + full.Id + '\');">' + 'Accept Lead' + '</button>';
              }
          }]
      });

      //-pending reviews table
      $('.reviews-table').DataTable({
          "ajax": "{!SITE_PREFIX}/PPDTJSONGENERATOR?Type=LeadReferral&input1={!SITE_Account.Id}",
          "columns": [
          {
              "mData": "Company",
              "mRender": function(data, type, full){
              return '<a onclick="leadReferralDetailJS(\'' + full.Id + '\', \'\');">' +data+ '</a>';
              }
          },{
              "mData": "Contact"
          },{
              "mData": "Title"
          },{
              "mData": "Location"
          },{
              "mData": "dateSubmitted"
          },{
              "mData": "Status"
          },{
              "mData": "action",
              "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                if(full.disableAction == true ){
                    return '<button type = "Button" class="btn primary" onclick="checkStatusJS(\'' + full.Id + '\');">' + 'Check Status' + '</button>';
                }else{
                    return '<button type = "Button" class="btn primary" disabled> Check Status </button>';
                }
              }
          }
          ]
      });

      //-active leads
      $('.available-leads-table').DataTable({
          "ajax": "{!SITE_PREFIX}/PPDTJSONGENERATOR?Type=LeadActive&input1={!SITE_Account.Id}",
          "columns": [
          {
              "mData": "Company",
              "mRender": function(data, type, full){
              return '<a onclick="leadActiveDetailJS(\'' + full.Id + '\', \'\');">' +data+ '</a>';
              }
          },{
              "mData": "Contact"
          },{
              "mData": "Title"
          },{
              "mData": "dateSubmitted"
          },{
              "mData": "dateApproved"
          },{
              "mData": "Action",
              "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                if(full.OpptyId != '' && full.OpptyId != null && full.OpptyId != 'null'){

                   return '<button type = "Button" class="btn primary" onclick="viewDealJS(\'' + full.OpptyId + '\');">' + 'View Opp' + '</button>';
                }else{
                    return '<button type = "Button" class="btn primary" disabled> View Opp </button>';
                }

              }
          }]
      });

    //-all leads
      $('.all-leads-table').DataTable({
          "ajax": "{!SITE_PREFIX}/PPDTJSONGENERATOR?Type=LeadAll&input1={!SITE_Account.Id}",
          "columns": [
          {
              "mData": "Company",
              "mRender": function(data, type, full){
              if(full.Status == 'Active'){
                return '<a onclick="leadActiveDetailJS(\'' + full.Id + '\', \'inbox\');">' +data+ '</a>';
              }else if(full.Status == 'Pending'){
                return '<a onclick="leadReferralDetailJS(\'' + full.Id + '\', \'referral\');">' +data+ '</a>';
              }else if(full.Status == 'Inbox'){
                return '<a  href = "#" onclick="leadInboxDetailJS(\'' + full.Id + '\', \'active\');">' +data+ '</a>';
              }else if(full.Status == 'Denied'){
                 return '<a  href = "#" onclick="leadDeclineDetailJS(\'' + full.Id + '\');">' +data+ '</a>';
              }
            }

          },{
              "mData": "Contact"
          },{
              "mData": "Title"
          },{
              "mData": "Location"
          },{
              "mData": "dateSubmitted"
          },{
              "mData": "Status"
          },{
              "mData": "Action",
              "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                  if(full.disableAction == false && full.Action == 'Check Status' ){
                    return '<button type = "Button" class="btn primary" onclick="checkStatusJS(\'' + full.Id + '\');">' + 'Check Status' + '</button>';
                }else if(full.disableAction == true && full.Action == 'Check Status' ){
                    return '<button type = "Button" class="btn primary" disabled> Check Status </button>';
                } else if(full.Action == 'Accept'){
                    return '<button type = "Button" class="btn primary" onclick="acceptLeadJS(\'' + full.Id + '\');">' + 'Accept Lead' + '</button>';
                } else if( full.Status == 'Active' && full.OpptyId != '' && full.OpptyId != null && full.OpptyId != 'null'){

                   return '<button type = "Button" class="btn primary" onclick="viewDealJS(\'' + full.OpptyId + '\');">' + 'View Opp' + '</button>';
                }else if(full.Status == 'Active' && (full.OpptyId == '' || full.OpptyId == null || full.OpptyId == 'null')){
                    return '<button type = "Button" class="btn primary" disabled> View Opp </button>';
                }else if(full.Status == 'Denied'){
                    return '---';
                }
              }
          }]
      });

});

</script>
```

```
<div class="title-group">
<h1> Leads &amp; Referrals</h1>
</div>
<apex:form >                
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!AcceptLead}" name="acceptLeadActionFn" rerender="waitingStatusLoad">
        <apex:param name="Id" assignTo="{!leadId}" value="" />
    </apex:actionFunction>
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!checkStatus}" name="checkStatusActionFn" >
        <apex:param name="Id" assignTo="{!leadId}" value="" />
    </apex:actionFunction>
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!ViewDeal}" name="viewDealActionFn" rerender="waitingStatusLoad">
        <apex:param name="OpptyId" assignTo="{!OpptyId}" value="" />
    </apex:actionFunction>

    <section data-uimodule="tabswitch" class="table">
        <div class="table-tabs">
          <button type = "button" data-tab="trigger" data-tabtarget="leads-inbox" href="#leads-inbox" class="tab {!IF(Type == 'Inbox' || Type == null || Type == '', 'is-active','')}">{!$Label.PP_Leads_Inbox} ({!inboxCount})</button>
          <button type = "button" data-tab="trigger" data-tabtarget="review" href="#review" class="tab {!IF(Type == 'Referral', 'is-active','')}">Referrals ({!referralCount})</button>
          <button type = "button" data-tab="trigger" data-tabtarget="available" href="#available" class="tab {!IF(Type == 'Active', 'is-active','')}">Active Leads ({!activeCount})</button>
          <button type = "button" data-tab="trigger" data-tabtarget="all-leads" href="#all-leads" class="tab {!IF(Contains(Type, 'All'), 'is-active','')}">All Leads ({!allCount})</button>
        </div>

        <div class="article-content">

            <article id="leads-inbox" data-tabcontent="leads-inbox" class="v-tab-content leads-inbox {!IF(Type == 'Inbox' || Type == null || Type == '', 'is-active','')}">
            <div class="leads-inbox-table-section {!IF(((Type == 'Inbox' || Type == null || Type == '') && (Id == null || Id == '')),'show-section', 'hide-section')}" id="leadInboxTable">

                <div class="m-heading visible-sm"><span class="icon previous"></span><a href="#" data-vtabback="back" class="m-go-back"> {!$Label.PP_Leads_Inbox} </a></div>                    
                <div class="leads-inbox-head leads-header-with-search">
                    <h3 class="s-heading">{!$Label.PP_Leads_Inbox} ({!inboxCount}) </h3>                
                    <div class="btn-container">
                        <apex:commandButton styleClass="btn primary submit-request-btn profile-margin-right"  Action="{!submit}" value="Submit Referral"/>
                        <span class="icon export" />
                        <span class="referral-list">
                        <apex:outputLink styleClass="export-btn pure-u spacer10 " value="{!$Page.PPLeadExport}">
                        <apex:param name="leadtype" value="Inbox"/>{!$Label.Export}
                        </apex:outputLink>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="sub-text">Our goal is for any available lead assigned to a partner to be accepted between 48 hours. Once we have accepted the lead, we will work with you to support you in the next step to help you win business. If you are unable to accept lead within 72hours, lead may be reassigned.</p>
                </div>

                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" class="leads-inbox-table responsive show-hidden-cols-default dataTable">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th class="all">Company</th>
                    <th class="not-mobile">Contact</th>
                    <th class="not-mobile">Title</th>
                    <th class="not-mobile">Location</th>
                    <th class="min-desktop">Date <br/>Assigned</th>
                    <th class="min-desktop">Days <br/>Remaining</th>
                    <th class="not-mobile">Action</th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="inbox-details-section child-tab-switch-section {!IF(((Type == 'Inbox' || Type == null || Type == '') && (Id != null || Id != '')),'show-section', 'hide-section')}" id="leadInboxDetails">
                <c:PP_LeadInbox_Detail />  
            </div>
            </article>

            <article id="review" data-tabcontent="review" class="v-tab-content review {!IF(Type == 'Referral' , 'is-active','')}">              
            <div class="leads-reviews-table-section {!IF((Type == 'Referral' && (Id == null || Id == '')),'show-section', 'hide-section')}" id="LeadTableRef">
                <div class="m-heading visible-sm"><span class="icon previous"></span><a href="#" data-tabback="back" class="m-go-back">Pending Reviews ({!referralCount}))</a></div>                    
                <div class="leads-inbox-head leads-header-with-search">
                <h3 class="s-heading">Pending Referrals ({!referralCount})</h3>
                <div class="export-to-excel btn-container">  
                    <span class="icon export" />
                    <span class="referral-list">
                    <apex:outputLink styleClass="export-btn pure-u spacer10 " value="{!$Page.PPLeadExport}">
                    <apex:param name="leadtype" value="Pending"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!$Label.Export}
                    </apex:outputLink>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <p class="sub-text">We strive to review and qualify submitted leads within 1-2 business days. If the status of a submitted lead has not been updated within 2 business days, you can click the 'Check Status' button for further details. When a pending lead has been approved or rejected you will be notified.</p>
                </div>
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" class="reviews-table responsive show-hidden-cols-default dataTable">
                   <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="all">Company</th>
                    <th class="min-desktop">Contact</th>
                    <th class="min-desktop">Title</th>
                    <th class="not-mobile">Location</th>
                    <th class="not-mobile">Date <br/>Submitted</th>
                    <th class="not-mobile">Status</th>
                    <th class="not-mobile">Action</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
              </table>
            </div>
             <div class="pending-leads-section child-tab-switch-section {!IF((Type == 'Referral' && (Id != null && Id != '')),'show-section', 'hide-section')}" id="leadReferralDetails">
                <c:PP_LeadReferral />  
            </div>
          </article>

           <article id="available" data-tabcontent="available" class="v-tab-content available {!IF(Type == 'Active', 'is-active','')}">

          <div class="active-leads-table-section  {!IF(Type == 'Active' &&(Id == null || Id ==''),'show-section', 'hide-section')}">
          <div class="m-heading visible-sm"><span class="icon previous"></span><a href="#" data-tabback="back" class="m-go-back">Active Leads ({!activeCount})</a></div>
              <div class="leads-inbox-head leads-header-with-search">
              <h3 class="s-heading">Active Leads ({!activeCount})</h3>
                 <div class="export-to-excel btn-container">  
                    <span class="icon export" />
                    <span class="referral-list">
                    <apex:outputLink styleClass="export-btn pure-u spacer10 " value="{!$Page.PPLeadExport}">
                    <apex:param name="leadtype" value="Pending"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;{!$Label.Export}
                    </apex:outputLink>
                    </span>
                </div>
               <p class="sub-text">Your account manager will work with you to create an opportunity and an account for each of your leads. If an account has been created you can click 'Register Deal' to  begin the deal registration process.</p>
            </div>

            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" class="available-leads-table responsive show-hidden-cols-default dataTable">
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="all">Company</th>
                    <th class="not-mobile">Contact</th>
                    <th class="not-mobile">Title</th>
                    <th class="min-desktop">Date <br/>Submitted</th>
                    <th class="min-desktop">Date <br/>Approved</th>
                    <!--<th class="not-mobile">Contact / <br/>Account Created</th> -->
                    <th class="not-mobile">Action</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
              </table> 
            </div>
           <div class="active-details-section child-tab-switch-section {!IF(Type == 'Active' &&(Id != null && Id !=''),'show-section', 'hide-section')}">
                <c:PP_LeadActive_Detail />  
            </div>
          </article>

          <article id="all-leads" data-tabcontent="all-leads" class="v-tab-content all-leads {!IF(Contains(Type, 'All'), 'is-active','')}">
          <div class="active-leads-table-section {!IF((Contains(Type, 'All') && (Id == null || Id == '')),'show-section', 'hide-section')}">
           <div class="m-heading visible-sm"><span class="icon previous"></span><a href="#" data-tabback="back" class="m-go-back">All Leads (3)</a></div>
            <div class="leads-inbox-head leads-header-with-search">
            <h3 class="s-heading">All Leads ({!allCount})</h3>
            <div class="export-to-excel btn-container">
                <span class="icon export" />
                <apex:outputLink styleClass="export-btn pure-u" value="{!$Page.PPLeadExport}">
                <apex:param name="leadtype" value="All"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;{!$Label.Export}
                </apex:outputLink>
            </div>
             <p class="sub-text">Your account manager will work with you to create an opportunity and an account for each of your leads. If an account has been created you can click 'Register Deal' to  begin the deal registration process.</p>
            </div>
             <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" class="all-leads-table responsive show-hidden-cols-default dataTable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="all">Company</th>
                  <th class="not-mobile">Contact</th>
                  <th class="not-mobile">Title</th>
                  <th class="min-desktop">Location</th>
                  <th class="min-desktop">Date <br/>Created</th>
                  <th class="not-mobile">Status</th>
                  <th class="not-mobile">Action</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
           </div>         

            <div class="inbox-details-section child-tab-switch-section {!IF((Type == 'Allinbox' && Id != null && Id != ''),'show-section', 'hide-section')}" id="LeadDetails">
                <c:PP_LeadInbox_Detail /> 
            </div>
            <div class="pending-leads-section child-tab-switch-section {!IF((Type == 'Allreferral' && Id != null && Id != ''),'show-section', 'hide-section')}" id="leadReferralDetails">
                <c:PP_LeadReferral />  
            </div>
            <div class="active-details-section child-tab-switch-section {!IF(Type == 'Allactive' && Id != null && Id != '','show-section', 'hide-section')}">
                <c:PP_LeadActive_Detail />  
            </div> 
            <div class="active-details-section child-tab-switch-section {!IF(Type == 'AllDeclined' && Id != null && Id != '','show-section', 'hide-section')}">
                <c:PP_LeadDeclined_Detail />  
            </div>

        </article>         

        </div>
    </section>    

</apex:form>
```

Comment: welcome to stackexchange .when you ask question ,Make sure to be precise and clear .Describe what you have done and what is not working or need help

Comment: @Mohith Shared the code for the Page. Please have a look. :)

Comment: what do you mean by loading data both in mobile and desktop ?Please be clear on what help you need here .

Comment: If you see the screen shot attached- the data in the table is being loaded in Horizontal Fashion(desktop view) & vertical (mobile view)..

Comment: Where's the rest of your page beginning with `<apex:page ....>`? What's in the header could be very relevant to the source of your problem.